# Angular2 Search Dynamic Results

Tags: angular, search, router

I am trying to implement Search in Angular2.

We want to have the Search, which will go and get results from the Rest Service. We want to implement it dynamically, so when the user types more than 5 characters, then it should do the search.

There are multiple examples (Hero's Example from Angular2 site) and we are able to achieve this. But the only issue we have is that the back button is not working.

We can't do a prefetch because of the size.

So, we implemented with the Router and a Search button. So when we click the search button, we do the search and pass as URL optional Parameters and we get the results from the parameters. That is also working.

But I really don't know how to implement search with dynamic fetching without the Search Button. We also want to have the back button work.

How can we go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

> But I really don't know how to implement search with dynamic fetching without the Search Button.

There are several examples online for this, but usually a search which hits an api goes along the lines of something like this:

```
//in HTML
<input id="searchInput" type="text"/>
{{search$ | async}}

 //in component
 let searchInput = document.querySelector('#searchInput');

    let search$ = Observable.fromEvent(searchInput, 'input') // create observable from input events
                            .debounceTime(500) // wait 500 milliseconds
                            .map(e => e.target.value) // extract the input value
                            .switchMap(value => http.get('url?search=' + value)); //switch to another obs and return it, in Angular would be the http call
```

Comment: This works, but when the user types back button the context is lost.